# spring jwt decoder openid token

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

External OAuth2 Provider doesn't have public JwkUri, so I tried too override default behavior using following code snippet:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DirectlyConfiguredJwkSetUri extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/oauth2/code/esia**", "**/code/esia**", "**esia**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user").fullyAuthenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .oauth2Client()
            .clientRegistrationRepository(this.clientRegistrationRepository)
            .authorizationCodeGrant()
            .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
                    this.clientRegistrationRepository, esiaConfig, signatureUtil, timeUtil))
            .accessTokenResponseClient(customAccessTokenResponseClient())
            .and().and().oauth2Login().tokenEndpoint().accessTokenResponseClient(customAccessTokenResponseClient())
            .and().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
}
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
 return  new CustomJwtDecoder();
}
}

class CustomJwtDecoder implements JwtDecoder {
@Override
public Jwt decode(String token) throws JwtException {
    System.out.println(token);
    return null;
}
}
```

However Spring Security somehow still uses default realization and I am getting the following error...

```
[missing_signature_verifier] Failed to find a Signature Verifier for Client Registration: 'esia'. Check to ensure you have configured the JwkSet URI.
```

Also, I tried to set custom AuthenticationProvider but spring ignores it.

I guess the catch is that spring`s OAuth2LoginConfigurer method init(B http) calls new OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider(accessTokenResponseClient, oidcUserService)

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue even with 5.2.x release. In my case, the real problem was not in the  JwtDecoder. I have fixed the issue by setting the jwk-set-uri property (you can change the provider name by the provider which you are using e.g okta, google etc.) :

```
security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/discovery/keys
```

Comment: nowadays its `/discovery/v2.0/keys`

Answer (score 4):

For 5.1.3.RELEASE it looks like you cannot get around this problem easily.

It stems from the [OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.getJwtDecoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.1.3.RELEASE/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/authentication/OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java#L200-L216)

This happens in [line 156](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.1.3.RELEASE/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/authentication/OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java#L156) which is a call to a private method

```java
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        ...
        OidcIdToken idToken = createOidcToken(clientRegistration, accessTokenResponse);
        ...
    }
```

The **one option** I see is if you make a copy of this code, and modify it yourself. Extending the class itself is not meaningful because all of the logic happens pretty much in the `authenticate` method. So you're still overriding it. then you add your provider using the `http.authenticationProvider` method

**Another option** is to override the [`SecurityConfigurerAdapter.postProcess`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.1.3.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java#L494) method of the `OAuth2LoginConfigurer` class and do something clever there. Like populating the [JWT decoder map](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.1.3.RELEASE/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/authentication/OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java#L81) through reflection.

Neither are admittedly preferred solutions. I believe that's why the refactoring happened for the 5.2 release.

Given the latest 5.2.x release then
You're almost there, but you must override the correct bean

```
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> jwtDecoderFactory() {
        final JwtDecoder decoder = jwtDecoder();
        return context -> decoder;

    }
```

and if you don't want to use lambdas

```java
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> jwtDecoderFactory() {
        final JwtDecoder decoder = jwtDecoder();
        return new JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration>() {
            @Override
            public JwtDecoder createDecoder(ClientRegistration context) {
                return decoder;
            }
        };

    }
```

How did I figure this out, well I took a look at the [OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/8f4f52edb978e99175e500b8c4e388b367c41097/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java#L493) class which does

```java
    JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> jwtDecoderFactory = getJwtDecoderFactoryBean();
```

and the private method that fetches the bean look like [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/8f4f52edb978e99175e500b8c4e388b367c41097/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java#L551-L561)

```java
    private JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> getJwtDecoderFactoryBean() {
        ResolvableType type = ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(JwtDecoderFactory.class, ClientRegistration.class);
        String[] names = this.getBuilder().getSharedObject(ApplicationContext.class).getBeanNamesForType(type);
        if (names.length > 1) {
            throw new NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException(type, names);
        }
        if (names.length == 1) {
            return (JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration>) this.getBuilder().getSharedObject(ApplicationContext.class).getBean(names[0]);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am using the latest version 5.1.3.Release and it doesn't have this Factory yet.

Comment: I've updated the answer. No good solution except to replace the entire authentication provider with your own.

Answer (score 1):

(Found this while looking for a solution to overriding the Jwt and Oidc Token validation. Filip's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520100/1981358) helped me get to the solution so I figured I'd add this to help anyone who follows the same search.)

For a time-travel testing scenario, our jvm clock was set months in the future. Login was failing due to the validations done on Jwt and Oidc token timestamp.

This addition worked for our app on Spring Security 5.2.1

```
@Bean
public JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> getJWTDecoder() {
    OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory factory = new OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory();
    factory.setJwtValidatorFactory(new Function<ClientRegistration, OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>>() {
        @Override
        public OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> apply(ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
            return new CustomTimestampIgnoringOidcTokenValidator(clientRegistration);
        }
    });
}
```

This just replaces the Default validators with a custom one which only validates the other claims.